# Sending email in PHP - Form

Tags: php, forms, xampp, phpmailer, sendmail

I have been trying to do tests to send an email through a form with php, but it does not work for me. The following message is returned: Error sending the email. That is, the value of the variable boolean $ sent is false.

I use Apache, XAMPP for Windows 10 with the Netbeans 8.2 development environment

Let's see if anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

This is the code that is giving faults:

```
<?php
$for = 'email@example.com';
$title = 'Sending email from PHP';
$message = '<html><head><title> Email with HTML </title></head>
            <body><h1> Email with HTML </h1>
            This is an email that is sent in HTML format
            <hr>Sent by my program in PHP</body></html>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n";
$headers. = 'Content-type: text / html; charset = utf-8 '. "\r\n";
$headers. = 'From: Name1 Name 2 <info@example.com>';
$sent = mail ($for, $title, $message, $headers);

if ($sent)
    echo 'Email sent correctly';
else
    echo 'Error in sending the email';
?>
```

Comment: That does look like a hard syntax error: `$ for` and so on is not valid PHP code

Comment: You're not concatenating properly after `...HTML format.'`, missing `.`. You're missing semi-colons after `$headers`. With that said, get yourself a decent IDE and it will pick up these things before hand. And enable php error reporting(if you haven't already).

Comment: have you tried sending it without headers?

Comment: At the time of copying and pasting the code, spaces have been added, and concatenation points have not been added. I still do not solve it.

Comment: If I checked to send the email without headers.

Comment: Basically the code is wrong and the question is wrong and the PHP mailer isn't set up, the code above I suspect was lifted from w3 schools and poorly at that .

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, you have some concatenation issues, I m not sure those actually exist in your code or are due to copy paste. Try following, take care of `$header` concatenation and semicolons `;` at the end of statements.

```
<?php
$for = 'email@example.com';
$title = 'Sending email from PHP';
$message = '<html>'.
        '<head> <title> Email with HTML </title> </head>'.
        '<body> <h1> Email with HTML </h1>'.
        'This is an email that is sent in HTML format.'
    '<hr>'.
    'Sent by my program in PHP'.
    '</body>'.
    '</html>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\ r \ n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text / html; charset = utf-8 '. "\ r \ n";
$headers .= 'From: Name1 Name 2 <info@example.com>';
$sent = mail ($for, $title, $message, $headers);

if ($sent)
    echo 'Email sent correctly';
else
    echo 'Error in sending the email';
?>
```

Comment: This is the value of the variables that are passed to the mail () function: email@example.com
Sending email from PHP
Email with HTML
This is an email that is sent in the HTM format sent by my PHP program
MIME version: 1.0 Content type: text / html; charset = utf-8 From: Name1 Name 2 <info@example.com>
Error in sending the email

Comment: do you have mail setting configured on your local machine?

Comment: No, can you explain to me what I have to do?

Comment: well in that case, you need to configure mail settings from `php.ini`, refer this link http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html , or there may be some smtp settings option in your framework

Comment: I want to send an email to the user that registers in my application. Only that.

Comment: I have reviewed the url that you have indicated to me and I have not been able to solve it. @nitin-p